# Dealing with extremely large strings

Tags: c#

Hey all, I am writing a logviewer application.  These logs are between 100-200 megs (almost never larger than that) of pure text.

My application will be not only used to make the reading of said logs easier, but to offer tons of options on parsing (filters/searches, ect).  Anywho, the files are on a network drive so I currently use FileStream and BufferedStream to read them in, which depending on the file takes about 15 seconds.

My first question is there a faster way to do this?  ReadLine made parsing easier, but clocked in at about 25 seconds.

Secondly, if the user is just playing around with one file alot (using different combos of filters and searches, whats the best way to deal with it in the applications memory? I mean I could just re-read it each time but thats silly.  I tried storing the whole file in a global StringBuilder which seemed to work, but I couldnt pass it on to other functions (OutOfMemoryException).

Whats the best way to deal with what ends up being a gigantic string? (Keep in mind no manipulations are being made, just pure reads/filter out what the user dosn't want to see.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Any reason you can't use one of the many freely available log viewers?

Comment: It's possible can you work on it in little peices and use a MemoryMappedFile to open very large files, and view it in peices?

Comment: @RQDQ what's wrong with writing an application?

Comment: @Mauricio - What's wrong with reinventing the wheel for the sake of it?

Comment: @Mauricio - there's nothing wrong with that if there isn't anything more high priority to be working on.  But the point is this is a space where people have already invested a lot of time and energy developing and testing tools. If you can take advantage of free tools for the common things (very little effort) and write code for the things that are more application specific, that can a bigger win than re-writing an application.

Comment: @RQDQ It's Ok but sometimes you just can't deliver a mix of tail grep and awk to a customer.

Comment: @Mauricio - totally agreed.  That's why I asked if it was possible and didn't just assume that he could.  There might be other reasons he can't use something off the shelf (unique log format, needs to be incorporated in a commercial application, just wants to learn about displaying long files).

Comment: @RQDQ Unique log format (very, annoyingly unique) is the main reason.  Also, its to help me learn about the system that outputs the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Hans suggests, read the file in chunks and do it on demand when the user needs to move about the file.  You can also try being smart and keeping nearby chunks in memory and discard distant chunks.

If you're doing this for fun, you might want to build a little in memory index as you process the file.  Meaning for each line you process, keep some metadata about the line number, where in the file it starts, and what kind of line it is.  That might make your options easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really have to read the entire file?  Read only half of it.  When the user is ready to look at another 'file' or set of dates, read the other half.  Pick your own number here to find the best balance.

Comment: Well the problem is that the message that are displayed only span an hour (and its still that large), so a user will frequently search for a particualr command and to see how it panned out for the whole hour.

Comment: Also the files are stored by year/month/day/ and then theres 24 files for all the hours in that day.

Comment: That a file happens to contain one hour worth of data is an irrelevant implementation detail.  There's no loss of generality to let the user see how it panned out for the whole 15 or 30 minutes.  The exact opposite argument could be made, why not show 2 hours worth of data.  Well, because that's hard.

Comment: Very true, didnt think of it that way.